# If $a|N$ and $b|N$ where $a,b$ are coprime , is it necessary that $(a \times b) |N$?

Tags: natural-numbers

In the above statement N , a , b are natural numbers . I was wondering whether the above statement is always true . If it is always true will anyone give me a simple reason or proof for it ? Please guide me .

Comment: Yes its always true. Consider the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: n has a unique prime decomposition, as do $a$ and $b$.

Comment: related and likely inspiration for this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3502984/if-a-polynomial-px-is-divisible-by-2-polynomials-x-a-and-x-b-is-it-necessa

Comment: If $ax+by=1$ then $Nax+bny=N$ and each term is divisible by $ab.$

Comment: i.e. $\ ab\mid aN,bN\,\Rightarrow\,ab\mid (aN,bN) = (a,b)N = N\ $ in gcd or ideal language (cf. [various forms of Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242))

Answer (score 0):

well yes, since: a/N and b/N  $\rightarrow$ $N = a* \alpha , N = b*\beta $

we have: $a/N \rightarrow a/b*\beta \rightarrow a/ \beta$ (because a and b are coprime by Gauss theorem)

Hence: $\beta = 0   or   \beta = k*a  \rightarrow  N = a*b*k$

Therefore: a*b/N